# Decrypting TLS app traffic from Android on Wireshark?

Tags: android, encryption, wireshark, tls1.2

I used [tPacketCaptute](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture) to capture an Android's traffic, I then loaded it into WireShark in my pc, however some of the traffic which I need looks to be encrypted with TLSv1.2

Is there anyway to decrypt it? or any other way to get decrypted Android traffic?

Comment: Almost certainly not, unless you control the server.